# Warning: foreach() argument must be of type array|object, null given in Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework

help me please this error

Controller :

```
    class  AlbumController extends AbstractActionController
{
    public $table;

    public function __construct(AlbumTable $table)
    {
        $this->table = $table;
    }

    public function indexAction()
    {
        return new ViewModel([
            'albums' => $this->table->fetchAll(),
        ]);
    }
    }
```

Model :

```
class AlbumTable {

    private $tableGateway;

    public function __construct(TableGatewayInterface $tableGateway)
    {
        $this->tableGateway = $tableGateway;
    }
    public function fetchAll()
    {
        $this->tableGateway->select();
    }
```

Module :

```
    <?php

namespace Album;



// Add these import statements:


use Laminas\Db\Adapter\Adapter;
use Laminas\Db\Adapter\AdapterInterface;
use Laminas\Db\ResultSet\ResultSet;
use Laminas\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway;
use Laminas\ModuleManager\Feature\ConfigProviderInterface;

class Module implements ConfigProviderInterface
{
    public function getConfig(): array
    {
        return include __DIR__ . '/../config/module.config.php';
    }

    // Add this method:
    public function getControllerConfig()
    {
        return [
            'factories' => [
                Controller\AlbumController::class => function ($container) {
                    return new Controller\AlbumController(
                        $container->get(Model\AlbumTable::class)
                    );
                },
            ],
        ];
    }

    public function getServiceConfig()
    {
        return [
            'factories' => [

                Model\AlbumTable::class => function($container) {
                    $tableGateway = $container->get(Model\AlbumTableGateway::class);
                    return new Model\AlbumTable($tableGateway);
                },
                Model\AlbumTableGateway::class => function ($container) {
                    $dbAdapter = $container->get(AdapterInterface::class);
                    $resultSetPrototype = new ResultSet();
                    $resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new Model\Album());
                    return new TableGateway('album', $dbAdapter, null, $resultSetPrototype);
                },

            ],
        ];
    }
}
```

index.phtml

```
    <?php
// module/Album/view/album/album/index.phtml:

$title = 'My albums';
$this->headTitle($title);
?>
<h1><?= $this->escapeHtml($title) ?></h1>
<p>
    <a href="<?= $this->url('album', ['action' => 'add']) ?>">Add new album</a>
</p>

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Artist</th>
        <th>&nbsp;</th>
    </tr>
    <?php
    foreach ($albums as $album) : ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?= $this->escapeHtml($album->title) ?></td>
            <td><?= $this->escapeHtml($album->artist) ?></td>
            <td>
                <a href="<?= $this->url('album', ['action' => 'edit', 'id' => $album->id]) ?>">Edit</a>
                <a href="<?= $this->url('album', ['action' => 'delete', 'id' => $album->id]) ?>">Delete</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

The error occurs in the index.phtml file. Please help, I've been struggling with this error for a long time. If you help I will be very grateful . i am use framework Laminas(zend) .
I'm trying to get a value from a table

That's all, I'm waiting for your suggestions

Comment: It *looks like* the error is just saying is that `$albums` is `null` in the foreach loop: `foreach ($albums as $album)` ... which implies something's broken further up the line, e.g.: `'albums' => $this->table->fetchAll()` is `null` in the controller's `indexAction()`

Comment: Do not know how to solve the problem?

Comment: I know how to make the error go away, add a simple sanity check before the loop, something like `if(is_iterable($albums))` - but the real issue you need to find is higher up, **why** is `$albums` null in the first place. I'm guessing you want to query the database table and return the result set to the view (beyond what Magento 2 does, I'm not that familiar with the nuts and bolts of laminas I'm afraid);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class AlbumTable {

    private $tableGateway;

    public function __construct(TableGatewayInterface $tableGateway)
    {
        $this->tableGateway = $tableGateway;
    }
    public function fetchAll()
    {
        *return* $this->tableGateway->select();
    }
```

Comment: Aaah looks like you found it - I missed the missing return as well :)